# Is it possible to print characters on top of each other without erasing the previous one in order to have both superscript and subscript?

Tags: python, unicode, jupyter-notebook, pretty-print

I am wondering if I can have `print()` outputs such as

in a terminal and/or an IPython/Jupyter Notebook. I want to develop a library working with toleranced dimensions and these types of pretty-printed outputs will come quite handy during development and testing.

What I know so far:

- There are escape characters such as Carriage Return `\r` that goes to the beginning of the line without erasing the existing characters and the Backspace `\b` that deletes the last character. For example `print("some text\bsome other text \rbingo", end="")` should give me `bingotexsome other text`. Anyway, when printing a new character the previous one is erased.
- I also know how to use Unicode characters to have superscripted/subscripted digits and plus/minus signs. For example, the `print('1.23\u207a\u2074\u2027\u2075\u2076')` will give me something like 1.23<sup>+4.56</sup> and `print('1.23\u208b\u2087.\u2088\u2089')` outputs close to 1.23<sub>-7.89</sub>. Although what unicode characters should be used for superscript/subscript decimal delimiters (in this case period/dot/point) is still debatable. There are multiple options for superscipted dot including also `\u0387` and `\u22c5`. However, AFIK there are no unicode characters suitable for subscripted dot. (more info [here](https://typedrawers.com/discussion/3551/variants-of-the-decimal-point))

what I don't know

- if there is an escape character or Unicode one that replicates the left arrow <kbd>←</kbd> key on the keyboard?
- how to print without erasing the pixels in the terminal? Is there a way to print/display characters on top of each other?
- and if none of the above is possible in a terminal, if/how I can control the HTTP/CSS outputs in a Jupyter Notebook to print both superscript and subscript at the same time?

Comment: That depends entirely on your terminal or interface; it's not something Python has any real control over. `print` simply writes bytes to a file.

Comment: @chepner I had suspected that there might be no universal solution that works regardless of the terminal and the OS. But even terminal/OS-specific solutions are also acceptable. Plus the Jupyter option should be universal, right?

Comment: In Jupyter, you'd use latex/MathJax and/or sympy. [This thread](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-use-jupyter-to-print-latex-into-code-for-math/10940?u=fomightez) contains lots of pointers to resources related to this for Jupyter. Also, you may want to see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/display-command-output-as-math-ipython-display-math/3125?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-add-markdown-inside-a-function-to-pretty-print-equation/2719/2?u=fomightez) to get familiar with the many options in Jupyter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jupyter Notebook/Lab this should work:

```
from IPython.display import Math

Math(r"1.23^{+4.56}_{-7.89}")
```

For convenience, you can package it in a class:

```
from IPython.display import Math

class PPrint:
    def __init__(self, base, sub, sup):
    self.base = base
    self.sub = sub
    self.sup = sup
    

    def  _ipython_display_(self):
        display(Math(f"{{{self.base}}}^{{{self.sub}}}_{{{self.sup}}}"))
```

Then you can create an instance e.g.:

```
x = PPrint("1.23", "+4.56", "-7.89")
```

and if you execute in a notebook either `x` or `display(x)`, it should appear as in your example.

Comment: This qualifies as the correct answer. But could you be kind to explain the `r` in front of the string?

Comment: I would like to use the `__str__` or `__repr__` methods of a class so when I use the `print()` function, they are automatically pretty-printed.

Comment: @FoadS.Farimani You should not overload `__str__` or `__repl__` here, since  these methods should return strings, not IPython objects. You can use instead e.g.` _ipython_display_` to display output nicely in the notebook environment. See my updated answer.

Comment: @FoadS.Farimani `r` indicates a raw Python string. In a raw string backslashes are interpreted as character literals, and not as parts of special character sequences (compare e.g. `print(r”a\nb”)` with `print(“a\nb”)`. Raw strings are useful when strings involve e.g. LaTeX code, but in your usage case there are no backslashes involved, so they are actually not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support. 